# Yet another blank page with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have read many similar title questions, but none of them worked for me...

The problem is that when I'm sending an cURL query to a website all I get is a blank page.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$action     = "http://www.website.com/index.php?section=login&do=process";
$fields     = array(
    'username'  => $user,
    'rememberMe'    => '1'
);

$login = curl_post($action, $fields);

var_dump($login);

    function curl_post($url, array $post = NULL, array $options = array()) 
    { 
        $defaults = array( 
            CURLOPT_POST            => 1, 
            CURLOPT_HEADER          => 0,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array('Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3', 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3",
            CURLOPT_URL             => $url, 
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1, 
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE    => 1, 
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 4, 
            CURLOPT_NOBODY          => false,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => http_build_query($post) 
        ); 

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
        if( !$result = curl_exec($ch)) 
        { 
            return(curl_error($ch)); 
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result; 
    }

?>
```

Of course I have my cURL enabled in PHP so its not about that.
If you have any ideas, please share!

## Update

I have also been trying adding the following lines at the top of my PHP file:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);  
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

But the problem still appears - result is a blank page. When I use `file_get_contents("http://website.com/");` I can see the page content, so it doesnt work with cURL only.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "blank page?" Your code sample suggests that you're assigning the result of the `curl` call to a variable, then trying to dump that. If *nothing* is being printed, your script might be encountering an error that's being suppressed by your `php.ini`.

Comment: @PeterSobot Yea, good point but I have been trying adding the ` ini_set("display_errors", 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and there is still a blank page. When I try to read the site content using the `file_get_contents("http://website.com/");` it is showing the page content so it seems that there is a problem with cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Running this locally and pointing it at Google, I see two things immediately:

1. PHP Notice: Undefined variable: user
2. Google returns a 'Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1' error page but probably because I'm trying to post to it

What happens when you define $user and try again?

Comment: Normally I have my `$user` variable defined. Just forgot to paste it in here... the results is blank page `;p`.

Comment: I also noticed your CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is set to 4. If the page takes longer than that to execute, you'd probably end up with a blank page. If you increase this to, say, 10 -- what happens?